# iReport composite classes

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I just started to use iReport and I can't find appropriate solution for my small problem :

I would like to create report based on class which is composite. It means that this class has another custom classes' objects as fields, in my example :

```
public class ModuleWithUsers {

private String objectName;
private Module module;
private User user;
}
```

Getters and setters included.

So, I would like to map fields which are in Module.class and User.class, however, I am getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'moduleId' on class 'class net.didorenko.model.composition.ModuleWithSafeguards'
```

How could I solve this problem?

My Module.class:

```
public class Module {

private Long moduleId;
private String moduleText;
private Double moduleRealization;

public Module(Long moduleId, String moduleText, Double moduleRealization) {
    this.moduleId = moduleId;
    this.moduleText = moduleText;
    this.moduleRealization = moduleRealization;
}

public Long getModuleId() {
    return moduleId;
}

public void setModuleId(Long moduleId) {
    this.moduleId = moduleId;
}

public String getModuleText() {
    return moduleText;
}

public void setModuleText(String moduleText) {
    this.moduleText = moduleText;
}

public Double getModuleRealization() {
    return moduleRealization;
}

public void setModuleRealization(Double moduleRealization) {
    this.moduleRealization = moduleRealization;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have public getters?

Comment: Yes, sure. I have them in current class for setting\getting module and I have them in Module.class to set id etc.

Comment: You need to create a [mcve], showing the datasource that you are passing and the related java class, (some jrxml would be nice to). You are probably missing getModuleId() in the class you are passing as datasource.

Comment: I will add this class to my topic, sure, that I have it